# TypeScript: Can I use typed strings?

Tags: typescript, types

How can I kind of narrow down the usages in the code of a string that can hold any value but has a semantic. E.g. a special ID or an email.

E.g. something like that:

```
type EMail = string;
type OrderID = string;

getUserEmail(): EMail;
getOrderById(id: OrderID): Order;
```

I can declare types but this still compiles:

```
getOrderById(getUserEmail());  // Does not throw a compiler error.
```

Is there a way to enforce that this is not possible?

Comment: You can check [this](https://basarat.gitbook.io/typescript/main-1/nominaltyping) out

Comment: Thanks, I think both the duplicate reply as well as this doc page addresses my point. I justs didn't know how this concept is called, so I didn't know "nominal typing" or "branded types".